# Snap to face problem: object is flipped 180 degrees and snapped to inside faces

Tags: mesh, objects, faces, normals, snapping

I'm trying to use the snap to face but when I move the object is snapping to the inside faces.

I've checked all the face's normal and there are all aligned correctly. The backface culling is checked. I've tried with all settings but still not working.I've tried also to flip normal and to rotate first the object 180 degress but the problem persist.

[image: When i move the object on the face is flipped 180 degrees]

When i move the object on the face is flipped 180 degrees[image: The object is snapped on the inside faces]

Comment: Hello :). Face snapping works with Z+ orientation of objects. You need to flip your mesh upside down (in edit mode) to make it snap correctly. Or just flip it after the snapping.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a function for do it automatically especially if you have an object with a lots of parents already setted?

Comment: Hey :). I'm not sure what you mean. Object with many children? Rotating a parent mesh in edit mode doesn't affect the children. Please expand... :)

Comment: I mean if there's a automatic function to align and fixed this without manually flip the obejct, in this case the object had just one parent, the bolts, so after I flipped the "disk" I had to recolocate the bolts, easy here that I have just two object parented but what if I had more objects parented and already positioned? Thank you so much for your support it worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

Snapping works with Z+ orientation, so just flip the origin point upside down.
To keep the parented objects in place, you can choose to only affect the parent.

1. Select your object
2. Go *View > Affect Only > Origins* and *Parents*
3. Rotate the Origin by 180°

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! That's what I needed thank you so much! How you can upload this animation? Is that a GIF? You do that with photoshop or there's something in Blender to do that? BC I think sometimes is better this then upload N images... Thank you!!!

Comment: Hey :). I use [Licecap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for the gifs. It's free, fast and easy to use.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner in Blender and face the same issue. This would be my solution—naive question. When I rotate by 180, no menu opens, and it snaps back to its original setting. What do I do wrong (I have a parent object - an empty that defines the orientation of the object it is the parent of).

Comment: Hi @Druss2k  :). Could you please post this comment as a [New Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)? You can link this one to provide context. More people will see it, and someone will surely help ;)