# Can I reset the origins and parents of a object to normal X Y Z

Tags: transforms, origin

Hello I'm new to blender and moving over from Maya. I have been trying to make a space ship in blender and been making some vents and panels for my space ship that I wanted to put on my ship. I used the snap to face tool for my objects to try and place them on the outside. The objects went on backwards so they faced the wrong way. I googled the problem and found a solution here [Snap to face problem: object is flipped 180 degrees and snapped to inside faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196365/snap-to-face-problem-object-is-flipped-180-degrees-and-snapped-to-inside-faces)

But then later on I wanted to scale my objects on the Y angel and of course now the x y z was wrong on the object so when I tried to scale it on the side it went completely the wrong direction... This is me trying to scale it in X direction with s + x and not working. https://gyazo.com/b88a0c4ba6928d2dad2c7deb1a3fd935 So I tried to google again to fix this but I couldn't find anything. I tried resetting the point with everything I know and I even tried to reset it with doing what I did in the first place but opposite and didn't work for some reason.

So if anyone know, please tell me. I tried to undo everything and go back to before I did this but need to get unlimited undos because i don't seem to have that yet. I realized too late that it would be a problem.
If I was not clear enough with what the problem is I'm more than glad to explain further.

Comment: before scaling, maybe try to apply the rotation so that the local orientation aligns with the global orientation?

Comment: Wow it was that easy! I been scratching my head on this for like 2 hours now. Yes that solved the problem thank you very much. Now I know til further. @moonboots

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before scaling, apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) so that the local orientation aligns with the global orientation.